# Get lines containing a string in a log file (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, unicode, powershell-2.0

I have a log file and I am trying to get the lines containing a specific pattern. 
I have converted it from UNICODE to UTF8 format in order to access the content in it.

The code I am using is

```
Select-String -pattern "Requesting response from" -path .\log_name.log
```

I have set the current directory to the one containing the log file.
But I do not see any results. What am I missing in here ? Am I converting the file to wrong format ?

Note: 
I have used

```
Get-Content $originallogFilePath |Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 .\log_name.log
```

to convert the file from UNICODE to UTF8.

Comment: Show us the pattern you are trying to match and some sample data would help.

Comment: Pettern is "Requesting response from"
Data is sth like 
"07/15/2014  Item removed from the list. \n
07/15/2014  Checking for input. \n
07/15/2014  Requesting response from the user. \n" The file dosent actually have \n I'm just adding to indicate a new line.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the encoding? `Select-String -Encoding` It supports `unicode` natively

Comment: @Eris : Whoa ! I missed that. I used -Encoding UNICODE and it works. I don't even need to convert the file. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: No problem, I added it as an answer so we can close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```
Select-String -Encoding unicode $logpath
```